# I want to add my website name in wordpress source code like this

Tags: custom-header

[image: RankMath Like it show in rankmath.com wordpress source code i want to add like this to in my website]

How can I add my website name to the top of the page 'view source' like the example above?

Comment: Can you fix your text? It's all capitalised, and missing letters, what word is DD?

Comment: You can either edit it into your theme's header.php - which might mean making a child theme so that it doesn't get overwritten by a theme update - or there's probably a hook you can use to do this from a plugin too.